# help me formalise this calculation

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a real valued function on $\mathbb R$. Consider the functions
$$
w_j(x) = \sup\left\{|f(u) − f(v)| : u, v \in \left[x − \frac{1}{j}, x + \frac{1}{j}\right]\right\}
$$
where $j$ is a positive integer and $x\in\mathbb R$. Define next,
$$
A_{j,n} = \left\{x\in\mathbb R : w_j(x) <
\frac{1}{
n}\right\}
\quad\text{and}\quad
A_n = \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_{j,n}
\quad n=1,2,\ldots
$$
Now let
$$
C = \{x \in\mathbb R : f \text{ is continuous at }x\}
$$
how do we write $C$ in terms of $A_n$?

Comment: What do you mean by
    `wj(x) = sup{|f(u) − f(v)| : u, v ∈ [x − 1 j , x + 1 j ]}`  
, specifically with `[ x - 1 j , x + 1 j ]`? And what about the last 'n' in `Aj,n = {x ∈ R : wj(x) < 1 n}`?

Comment: @AndreasT its x-1\j, x+1\j

Comment: @anonymous like that?

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer yes

Comment: @anonymous I think you mean "yes, thank you". Also I noticed you haven't accepted any answers despite the fact that you've asked four questions.

Comment: @GitGud oh sorry i forgot to say thanks, actually i am new here and exploring options here, and please tell me how to accept any answer i like,

Comment: @GitGud sory that was union of Aj,n over j

Comment: Are you sure that you don’t want $$A_n=\bigcup_{j=n}^\infty A_{j,n}\;?$$

Comment: To accept an answer, you go to the top right corner of an answer, where the up/down arrows are. Below the down arrow is a checkmark. If you click that, then it will turn green and you will have accepted their answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i want it frm 1 to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: With the definitions revised so that $$A_n=\bigcup_{j\ge 1}A_{j,n}\;,$$ we have $x\in A_n$ if and only if there is some $j\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\in A_{j,n}$. Intuitively speaking, this says that $x\in A_n$ if and only if $|f(u)-f(v)|<\frac1n$ whenever $u$ and $v$ are sufficiently close to $x$. (It’s a little more complicated than that, since a set of real numbers less than $\frac1n$ doesn’t necessarily have a supremum strictly less than $\frac1n$, but that’s good enough to get the right intuition.) If we could say that for **every** positive integer $n$, it would sound a lot like saying that $f$ is continuous at $x$. That suggests that you should try to prove that $$C=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n\;.\tag{1}$$

Once you get the idea that $(1)$ ought to be true, proving it is pretty straightforward. Show that if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $x\in A_n$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then show that if $f$ is not continuous at $x$, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\notin A_n$.